# How to scroll up a child of a scroll view when softinputkeyboard is shown

Tags: android

Is it possible to scroll a scroll view when the scroll view's display height is less than the physical display height of the device?

I tried with few methods, but unable to make the content up,when input keyboard is shown.

I want to to scroll up an EditText which is a child of a scrollView ,when softinputkeyboard is shown.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```